# GKE create Node Pool with Secondary Node Pool Pod IP Range via Terraform

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, gke-networking

I have a GKE cluster with pod address config as follows:

- **Cluster pod address range (default)     [pod-subnet]/17**

This [pod-subnet]/17 subnet is present in a shared GCP Project. I had exhausted those IPs once. So, I am creating a separate node pool for some services where I want to use a different subnet [pod2-subnet]/18, for Node Pool Pod Address Range.
When I create a node pool via Console, there is this option:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lThuy.jpg]
[image: pods is default, pods2 is custom]

But I couldn't find usable config in [Terraform GKE Doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool). Trying to achieve [GKE Node Pool API Doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.clusters.nodePools#nodenetworkconfig).
I tried few of the following configs but they are not supported.

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "node_pool_1" {
name = "${var.pool_name_1}"
location = var.cluster_location
node_locations = [
    var.pool_zone,
    ]
cluster = "app-${var.cluster_name}"
# node_count = 1
max_pods_per_node = 10

autoscaling {
    min_node_count = 1
    max_node_count = 300
}
# 1
ip_allocation_policy {
    pod_range = "pods2"
}
# 2
network = "projects/shared-project-1/global/networks/shared-network-1"
subnetwork = "projects/shared-project-1/regions/${var.region}/subnetworks/k8s-subnet"
network_config {
    create_pod_range = true
    pod_range = "pods2"
}
## 
node_config {
    ## Preemptive Node Pool
    preemptible = true
    machine_type = var.machine_pv_e1

    metadata = {
        disable-legacy-endpoints = "true",
        owner = "abc",
        project = "app1",
        team = "spirit"
    }

    labels = {
        app = "prod-${var.app1}",
        pool = "n2",
        pool_type = "pv",
        zone = "d",
        env = "prod"
    }
    service_account = "app-sa@project101.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    oauth_scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"]


    tags = [var.node_tag]
}
}
```

Both (#1, #2) of them did not work. As all these parameters are not allowed.

How do I define which Secondary Node Pool Pod IP CIDR range to pick while creating a node pool via terraform?

Answer (score 0):

Let’s suppose that you used Terraform to create the cluster in GKE too. Then, your “tfvars” file will need to be edited. That file should contain a variable called something like “gke_node_count”. You must set up that number with the node count you want. Change the machine type, and then save the file, and finally run the “terraform apply” command. Ensure that the K8s’ node is getting modified by reviewing the plan, and then confirm the run. It can take up to 5 minutes for you to get the new node or nodes available.

This will interrupt the running workloads because they are gonna be migrated to the new node pool.

On the other hand, if the cluster was not created with Terraform or, for example, OpsBase, this process is not going to work.

Comment: The cluster was created by Terraform only, but what I'm trying to do it to create a node pool with non default podIpv4CidrBlock (default one is configured in the cluster). The screenshot config is from where I am creating a node pool on GKE Console UI. I am looking for terraform config for this.

Comment: Then yes, the process I described above should work. Edit the “tfvars” file as if you were going to increase the "gke_node_count", and when you change a single little thing more, like the Machine Type, the “terraform apply” command creates the nodepool.

Comment: You are suggesting is how to increase node count. What i'm asking is, terraform flag, for setting secondary node pool pod address range, while creating a node pool.

Comment: I know it seems like I suggested to increase the node count but the behavior is that, if you try to increase the node count, and in the process you change something like the Machine Type, the count is not going not going to get increased but a new node pool is going to be created, that's why I recommended you to change a value like the Machine Type.

Comment: Again, I am trying to allocate different subnet to a new node pool via terraform. There's an option to do that in GKE Console UI (have shared the screenshot in the question itself). When we create a node pool without specifying the subnet, it picks up the cluster default subnet. I am trying to avoid that and allocated a new subnet instead.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same problem while using the subnets from my Shared VPC project, Below is the code which will take the secondary IP ranges form the subnets:

```
module "gke" {
  source                     = "terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google//modules/beta-private-cluster-update-variant"
  project_id                 = var.project_id
  name                       = var.cluster_name
  regional                   = var.regional
  region                     = var.region
  network                    = var.network
  network_project_id         = var.network_project_id 
  subnetwork                 = var.subnetwork
  ip_range_pods              = var.ip_range_pods
  ip_range_services          = var.ip_range_services
  create_service_account     = var.create_service_account
  service_account            = var.service_account
  enable_private_endpoint    = var.enable_private_endpoint
  enable_private_nodes       = var.enable_private_nodes
  master_ipv4_cidr_block     = var.master_ipv4_cidr_block
  remove_default_node_pool   = var.remove_default_node_pool
  http_load_balancing        = var.http_load_balancing
  default_max_pods_per_node  = var.default_max_pods_per_node
  node_metadata              = "GKE_METADATA_SERVER"   
  identity_namespace         = "enabled"

  node_pools = [
    {
      name               = var.np1_node_pools_name
      machine_type       = var.np1_machine_type
      min_count          = var.np1_min_count
      max_count          = var.np1_max_count
      disk_size_gb       = var.np1_disk_size_gb
      disk_type          = var.np1_disk_type
      service_account    = var.service_account
      pod_range          = var.np1_ip_range_pods 
      auto_upgrade       = var.np1_auto_upgrade
      auto_repair        = var.np1_auto_repair
    }
  ]

}
```

Please note that the field pod_range will take the IP of the secondary IP range, the name of the IP range should be given instead of giving the actual IP address here.